# stderr: No ECDSA host key is known for gitlab.com and you have requested strict checking.and Host key verification failed

Tags: jenkins, gitlab

ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'

getting error while cloning the gitcode using jenkins pipeline

Answer (score 15):

to solve above issue just change "Host Key Verification Strategy" to "Accept first connection"
Dashboard > Manage Jenkins > Configure Global Security > Git Host Key Verification Configuration. Then in Host Key Verification Strategy select Accept first connection.

Comment: [@B. Lakshmi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20326825/b-lakshmi) In Jenkins 2.401.3 it's "Dashboard > Manage Jenkins > Security > Git Host Key Verification Configuration"

Comment: You can also select **Manually provided keys** and paste what you have in your own known_hosts file.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in a php project. I ran `ssh-keygen -R "gitlab.com"` and it worked